# Find the amount of rows that follow certain rules including starting date and boolean value in this day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has 2 columns named "timestamp" and "is_holiday". Timestamp goes with "yyyy-mm-dd"
, "is_holiday" goes with 0 or 1 depending if there is a holiday this day or not. I want to count the amount of holidays in certain years, which means i want to count:
("timestamp" starts with yyyy(example:2015)) and ("is_holiday" is 1 this day) and print the amount of holiday days during this year. I'm doing this on python with pandas module.

I also want to know why do we have to use df[df[column] & df[column]] ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
^             -------------------------          ^ these two brackets while refering to

different conditions and have to include conditions in these square brackets

```
len(df[df['is_holiday']==1 & (df["timestamp"].astype("str").str.contains('2015'))])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's create an example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': [4, 5, 6],
})
```

Then the inner condition

```
df['a']==1
```

returns

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

which means it returns the condition if each row contains the column 'a' has the 1 value it shows row 0 satisfy the condition so

```
df[df['a']==1]
```

returns

```
    a   b
  0 1   4
```

it suits to two condition which means

```
df[df['a']==1 & (df['b']==4)]
```

will return

```
    a   b
  0 1   4
```

Hope this will help you~

```
 result_str_contains = df[df["timestamp"].astype("str").str.contains('2015') & (df['is_holiday'] == 1)].count()['is_holiday']
```

Comment: That's such a cool explanation from you, can't be more grateful for this. But i still got  a question: why did you put .count()["is_holiday"] at the end? What does it do?

Comment: df[df["timestamp"].astype("str").str.contains('2015') & (df['is_holiday'] == 1)] this will give you the dataframe that satisfy your condition, .count() will count for the selected dataframe, and add ["is_holiday"]  will count for the specific column. You can have a try to delete the ["is_holiday"], you will get the idea~

Comment: Wow! That's a nice explanation, but why isn't ['is_holiday'] inside .count?

Comment: This is the built-in method in pandas. Try to see this https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html

Comment: Note that you not necessarily need the outer `df[condition_mask]` if you just want the length `condition_mask.sum()` will return you the amount of True values.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for your suggestions!